# How to use impdp to import exported DB into a specific Oracle DB instance?

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to know if it is possible to import a DB using the command impdp into a specific Oracle instance? Currently, I have 3 DB instances and I would like to import it to only one specific instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "specific Oracle instance"?  The only time that "instance" and "database" are not synonyms in Oracle is when you have one database using RAC to create multiple instances.  If you are asking whether you can import into just one instance in a RAC cluster, the answer would be no because RAC is a shared storage architecture.

Comment: Hi Justin, what I mean is since I have several instance on my Oracle as show below. I would like to import the DB into Instance "Test". Is it possible ? Thanks!
Service "oracledb" has 2 instance(s).
Instance "test", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Handler(s):
    "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
       LOCAL SERVER
Instance "oracledb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Handler(s):
    "DEDICATED" established:84419 refused:0 state:ready
       LOCAL SERVER

Comment: Hi Justin, the reason I's asking is because there exists the same tables in instance "oracle". I want to import the DB into instance test so not to override what's in instance "oracle". Thanks!

Comment: @Joie Tamayo, is there any solution for this. I am having 2 oracle instances. I want to import to the 1st instance. But whenever i doing that, it  is giving connnection error.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

```
impdp 'sys/<password>@oimdb AS SYSDBA' DIRECTORY=dump_dir DUMPFILE=export.dmp LOGFILE=import.log TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE
```